# How to alter the character set on the mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I dumped all `character_set_*` variables in my MySQL database, since I wanted MySQL to have a 'utf8' character set. But even after using the `set names` command only few of the variables have changed. Have I configured this correctly?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | latin1 |
| character_set_connection | latin1 |
| character_set_database   | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | latin1 |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.29 sec)

mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.29 sec)
```

Comment: I recently dealt with this same issue a few months ago, posted a blog article about it. http://melikedev.com/2011/07/26/mysql-percona-setting-character-sets-and-collations-to-utf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALTER DATABASE your_db_name CHARACTER SET utf8;